# Cannot update foxpro driver version in system odbc

Tags: odbc, foxpro

Good Days,

I would like to ask why my FoxPro driver in system odbc cannot be updated even I downloaded the latest driver from Microsoft and install it.

I had use control panel to uninstall the FoxPro driver and then install it again. I found that it also cant work.

I hint the error below :

[image]

This is the version I browse from odbc:

[image]

My pc is window 7.
I appreciate it very much if someone know the solution.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [OLE DB driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).

Which is version 6.x as shown here:[image]

Answer (score 0):

VFP doesn't have an ODBC driver since version 6. For all versions (pre and post 6) there is OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB) - version 9.0.00.5815).